# AWS EC2, I need to have more RAM without having to have better instance family for my EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have multiple EC2 instances with a CPU utilization below 15% at all times. I want to downgrade these instances, but I need the extra RAM that comes with the better instance type.
Is there a way to have the RAM required without having to have a better instance type?

Comment: Look through the available instance types and try to find one that fits. You cannot have half of the features of one type and half of the other.

Comment: No. You need to change instance type to one with more ram.

Comment: If you need more RAM, maybe have a look at the [Memory optimized instance types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#Memory_Optimized).

Answer (score 1):

An Amazon EC2 **Instance Type** provides a certain amount virtual hardware. It includes:

- A particular **type** of CPUs
- A particular **count** of CPUs
- A particular amount of **RAM**
- Some of them include a particular amount of directly-attached disk storage ("Instance Store")

Within an Instance Family, doubling the size of the instance (eg moving from `large` to `2xlarge` will double each of these attributes.

If you desire a **different ratio of RAM:CPU**, then you should select an instance type **from a different Instance Family**.

See: [Amazon EC2 Instance Types - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)